# Array prints out zeros

Tags: java, arrays

I have this program which gets input from user and creates the array. Then the user will also specify the values to be placed into the array. My program is able to get the input from the user and is able to print it out. But when i add extra methods which processes these inputs and returns it, the program keeps on printing out zeros. I am unable to identify the mistake in my codes. I suspect that the mistake is somewhere in the passing of the array. I want to learn from my mistake and correct it. Please help me to go through my codes and check where the mistake lies. I have included parts of my codes where i think the problem might lie.

Thank you in advance!!!

Code:

```
class Matrix {
int size;
int matrix[][];
public Matrix() {}

public Matrix(int matrix[][],int size) {
    this.size = size;
    this.matrix = new int[size][size];

}

public int [][] opt(String op, String t){

    if(op.equals("Reflect")){

        if(type.equals("x")){
            rX();
        }

    }
    return matrix;
}

private void rX(){
    int i;
    int j;

    int array[][] = new int[size][size];

    for (i=0; i< size; i++){
        for (j=0; j < size; j++){
            array[size-(i+1)][j] = matrix[i][j];
        }
       matrix = array;

    }

class Transform {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix(tempArray, size);
    opt = sc.nextInt();

 for (i=0; i<opt; i++){
        String op = sc.next();
        String t = sc.next();
        tempArray = matrix.opt(op,t);

    }

   }
```

Comment: I think the problem is in `matrix = array;`

Comment: The constructor of `Matrix` initializes the variable `matrix` to all zeroes. Why do you have a parameter to the constructor that you don't use at all? And what is the value of `tempArray` that is passed to the constructor from `main`? And what is supposed to happen in `rX()`? My first guess is that you want to reverse rows in the matrix, but by having the `matrix = array` inside the outer for-loop all values for `i` other than 0, will be 0...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in how you initialize the array in the class constructor:

```
public Matrix(int matrix[][],int size) {
    this.size = size;
    this.matrix = new int[size][size];
}
```

Typically when you pass in arguments through the constructor, they are used to initialize class variables. I think what you want to consider is this change:

```
public Matrix(int matrix[][],int size) {
    this.size = size;
    this.matrix = matrix;
}
```

this.matrix refers to the class variable named matrix, and the second matrix variable refers to the argument variable named matrix. This way the argument int matrix[][] will be used to initialize the int double array in the instance of Matrix, and your matrix will not be all zero's anymore.

Comment: I think that is the first problem, but looking at `rX()`, I think most of the matrix is set to `0` again. Unless that was the intention, `matrix` will revert back to almost all zeroes even if the initialization is fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much, can't believe that i overlooked such a trivial thing. I am such an idiot. And @Johanneke, you were right, i made a mistake there. I placed a double for loop out side of the first double loop and the problem is resolved. Thank you very much for your kind help. I understand my mistake now :)